# Scrape text with playwright is slow using locator

Tags: node.js, playwright

I'm try to use Playwright to scrape some cities using nodejs. I call locator method about 300 times with different selectors with code like this:

```
 const finishedAds = await page.locator('div.iva-item-sellerInfo-_q_Uw span.iva-item-text-Ge6dR').innerText();
```

Total execution time was about 8 seconds.

Ok, I rewrite my program using cherio and execution time was less then 1 second.

Really the locator method works very slowly - or I didn't use it correctly?
(I scrape a list inside div, that has 50 children div with some info)

Comment: If it's 8x faster with Cheerio, just use that, right?

Comment: yes, about 16x (in my case)

Comment: Yeah, that's expected. Cheerio is working on the static HTML that you've presumably parsed once, while Playwright makes an expensive subprocess call to the browser that works on the live DOM. There's a cost to the real-time and dynamic nature of browser automation. Static HTML traversal is basically always going to be faster. Seems like you have your solution, then, but be wary of premature optimization. Often, blocking images, resources, JS, or doing your selection in a single `evaluate` call may be better ways of speeding things up.

Comment: >>Often, blocking images, resources, JS>> Yes, I did it :) I think about evaluate - but don't try it, my second try is cherio. But I don't know that locate is so slow :) I scrape SPA sity that have dynamic HTML and I need to emulate some user action to access to some HTML parts.